# C++ "no match for operator >>" when comiling on -std=c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, ifstream, complextype

I have function that loads data (numbers) from file to complex table. Everything is compiling without error on -std=c++98, but when I want to compile with -std=c++11, probem with operator >> occurs.

```
template <typename T> void load(char name[], complex<T> table[], int len) {

    ifstream dane;
    dane.open(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * len; i++)
            (i % 2 == 0 ? dane >> table[i / 2].real() : dane >> table[(i - 1) / 2].imag());

    dane.close();
}


no match for 'operator>>' in 'dane >> (table + ((sizetype)(((unsigned int)((i + -1) / 2)) * 16u)))->std::complex<double>::imag()'
no match for 'operator>>' in 'dane >> (table + ((sizetype)(((unsigned int)(i / 2)) * 16u)))->std::complex<double>::real()
```

Under that there is infromation about many canditates which cannot convert argument from double.

So what can I do, to run it with c++11 standard?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/imag none of these return reference, hence the value is not lvalue but rvalue(I believe), and you cannot assign to rvalues(Imagine writing `dane >> 5;`, the same deal. You will have to read into temporary variable and then depending on i you will either write to real or imag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/imag

None of these return reference, hence the value is not lvalue but rvalue(I believe), and you cannot assign to rvalues(Imagine writing `dane >> 5;`, the same deal. You will have to read into temporary variable and then depending on i you will either write to `real` or `imag`.

(Example of writing: `table[i /2].real(myTemporaryVariable);`)

Edit:

Working function:

```
template <typename T> void load(char name[], complex<T> table[], int len) {

ifstream dane;
dane.open(name);

for (int i = 0; i < 2 * len; i++)
{
    double read;

    dane >> read;

    if (!(i%2)) table[i / 2].real(read);
    else        table[(i - 1) / 2].imag(read);
}

dane.close();
```

}

Also I have no idea why it compiles with -std=c++99

Comment: There's no reason to have `read` declared outside of the `for` loop. You should put it inside and save some namespace clutter.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand. But also don't know why it was running properly earlier...

Answer (score 1):

With C++11 the real() and imag() members of std::complex became constexpr, which implies const. Therefor there is no operator>> for them anymore. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/imag for the specification. I don't see how this construction can work in C++11.

Comment: @Podipie Code::Blocks with what compiler?